# ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT not detecting unique conflicts in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, sql-returning

I have this line of code

```
        db.execute("""INSERT INTO warelo.users (email, username, hash, wg_puid) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT users_email_username_user_id_key DO NOTHING
    RETURNING (user_id)""",
    (request.form.get("email"), request.form.get("username"), hash, wg_puid))
    result = db.fetchall()
```

What it's supposed to do is register a user, and to make sure username and emails are unique, if either the user's username, email or user_id already exist, to do nothing. The code itself *runs*, but I'm still inserting duplicate emails and usernames. It seems that the ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT is never triggering, even when it should. What's wrong with my code here?

[image: My unique constraints here:]

Comment: All 3 columns need to be already in table (as a single row) for conflict to trigger. But from what you wrote it seems like you want it to trigger if at least one of those is already in use, correct?

Comment: The constraint demands the **combination** of name and address and even id to be unique. Having the id in it too makes the constraint totally pointless assuming that the ids, that are inserted are already unique. And even if id wasn't in it, single values of the name could occur more than once, as long as the address is different. Analog for the address.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Correct.

Comment: @stickybit is the solution then to have one constraint for each?

Comment: @Coal143: Seems like that's what you actually want, yes.

Comment: You could have one constraint for each, but I think that ON CONFLICT supports only one conflict per query, so you won't be able to use that. You would have to old school `EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN SELECT id FROM .. END`

Comment: What's the proper syntax here?
`db.execute("""INSERT INTO warelo.users (email, username, hash, wg_puid) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)
        RETURNING (user_id)
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN DO NOTHING""",
        (request.form.get("email"), request.form.get("username"), hash, wg_puid))
        result = db.fetchall()` doesn't seem to work